# python pandas - input values into new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe below of spending of 4 persons.
There is an empty column called 'Grade'. 
I would like to rate those who spent more than $100 grade A, and grade B for those less than $100. 
What is the most efficient method of filling up column 'Grade', assuming it is a big dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['Bob','Ken','Steve','Joe'],
             'Spending':[130,22,313,46]})
df['Grade']=''
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas: Add column based on other column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424567/python-pandas-add-column-based-on-other-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Grade']= np.where(df['Spending'] > 100 ,'A','B')
print (df)
  Customer  Spending Grade
0      Bob       130     A
1      Ken        22     B
2    Steve       313     A
3      Joe        46     B
```

**Timings**:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Customer':['Bob','Ken','Steve','Joe'],
             'Spending':[130,22,313,46]})

#[400000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [129]: %timeit df['Grade']= np.where(df['Spending'] > 100 ,'A','B')
10 loops, best of 3: 21.6 ms per loop

In [130]: %timeit df['grade'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'A' if row['Spending'] > 100 else 'B', axis = 1)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.08 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way to do that would be to use lambda function with an apply function.

```
df['grade'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'A' if row['Spending'] > 100 else 'B', axis = 1)
```

Comment: no, `apply` is very slow. Please check timings in my answer.

Comment: @jezrael valid point. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166348/why-is-np-where-faster-than-apply