# How can I create a new column calculated from two other columns (based on location)

Tags: python, pandas

I've been following other stackoverflow questions (e.g. [Python Pandas: Add column based on other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424567/python-pandas-add-column-based-on-other-column)) to develop code to create a new column with values being the difference between, let's say, columns 'a' and 'b'.

I understand that the syntax is fairly straightforward, but having problems with specifying the column to use for the calculation using iloc:

```py
df['diff'] = df.iloc[:, 0] - df.iloc[:, -1]
```

I get the error:

```py
ufunc 'subtract' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')
```

Comment: why not `df['c'] = df['a']- df['b']`?

Comment: I am hoping to iterate this over other dataframes where the values in 'b' might actually be in column 'x' (the last column in my dataframes are referring to outside temperature, for example)

Comment: So the problem is that you have object type values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Náthali said as long as you are using numerical values the following will work

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,2),
                 columns=["a", "b"])
```

- `df.iloc[:, 0] - df.iloc[:, -1]`     # 178 µs ± 1.34 µs
- `df["a"] - df["b"]`                  # 84.1 µs ± 1.02 µs
- `df["a"].values - df["b"].values`    # 5.39 µs ± 84.2 ns
- `- df[["a", "b"]].diff(axis=1)["b"]` # 702 µs ± 32.4 µs

You can't subtract strings.

Answer (score 1):

i am using pandas 0.23.4 and it works

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 3, 4, 3], 'B': [3,2,6,4]})
A['diff'] = A.iloc[:,0] - A.iloc[:, 1]                                                                                

In [11]: A                                                                                                                     
Out[11]: 
       A    B  diff
0    4.0  3.0   1.0
1    3.0  2.0   1.0
2    4.0  6.0  -2.0
3    3.0  4.0  -1.0
new  NaN  NaN   NaN
```

- which version of pandas are u using?
- check type of your columns too

Comment: - I'm currently using 0.23.0, will run update now to see if this helps. Great point re. checking the column types, they're in float64.

Comment: The negative values in the column is causing issues with converting all to float64 - will update when I've succeded.